# How to decode this particular JSON model?

Tags: ios, json, swift

EDIT 2:

After changing the Model struct and calling the JSON decoder without a completion handler, I have managed to get this to work. Thank you all for your help.

Fixed code:

Model

```swift
import Foundation

struct RatesResponse: Decodable, Hashable{
    let rates: [String: Double]
}
```

Decoder Class

```swift
import Foundation

class RatesModelData{
    public var rateCurrency = [String]()
    public var rateValue = [Double]()

    public func getRates(currency: String){
 
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=\(currency)")
        else {
            print("URL is invalid")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do{
                    let ratesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(RatesResponse.self, from: data)
                    
                    for rate in ratesResponse.rates{
                        self.rateCurrency.append(rate.key)
                        self.rateValue.append(rate.value)
                    }
                    
                    print(self.rateCurrency)

                } catch {
                        print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

I have changed let rate = Rates to let rates = Rates, modified the  decoder class to the following and added a do/catch statement however I am now getting the error "The data given is invalid JSON". I have updated the code snippets as well.

---

I have this json model:

https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=usd

and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to decode it properly. I know its a dictionary and has to be decoded as such but i'm struggling to wrap my head around what i'm doing wrong.

Model:

```
struct RatesResponse: Decodable, Hashable{
    let rates : Rates
}

struct Rates: Decodable, Hashable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
}
```

Decoder Class:

```
class RatesModelData{

    public func getRates(currency: String, _ completionHandler: @escaping(Rates) -> Void){
 
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=\(currency)")
        else {
            print("URL is invalid")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "ACCEPT")
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response, error in
            do{
            if let data = data {
            
                if let ratesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(RatesResponse?.self, from: data){
                    completionHandler(ratesResponse.rates)
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else{
                    print("Error with response: \(response)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error Thrown : \(error)")
                    return
                }
           } catch {
                print(error)
           }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

I ideally want to get this to be displayed in a list view (SwiftUI), but for now just asking for some advice as to where i've gone wrong with my decoding.

Comment: let rate : Rates -> let rates : Rates

Comment: First, tell me where you found that sample code, because the person who is using `try ?` for JSON decoding needs a good talking to. Use `do/try/catch` and print the resulting error and you will see what is going wrong, which is that the json has `rates` and you have `rate`

Comment: I've edited my post after implementing both your suggestions and i'm getting an error saying my json is invalid, have I declared my model incorrectly?

Comment: You want `decode(RatesResponse.self, from: data)` - You can't decode an optional.

Comment: Take care of easier keys (success, base, date), first, to see if you can read them.

Comment: Add `if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(str) }` and you will probably see that the URL is returning a cloud flare rate-limiting page in the first instance.  This can't be decoded as JSON.  Their API is broken until they get rid of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the struggles of parsing JSON into structs last year so I feel comfortable helping you out. It's definitely a challenging concept to wrap your head around:

First, let me explain what's wrong with your structs:

```swift
struct RatesResponse: Decodable, Hashable{
    let rates : Rates
// "rates" is a root-level key in your JSON. 
// You're giving it the value of your structure Rates,
// which also has a key titled "rates".
}

struct Rates: Decodable, Hashable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
}
```

Here's what your JSON would look like if these structs could be used to parse it:

```json
{
    "rates": {
        "rates": {
            "AED": 3.671827,
            "AFN": 80.098152
        }
    }
```

In your actual JSON, your "rates" key has the value of an object (or dictionary, which is nothing more than an array with keys and values) I'm sure you don't want to make a struct with a variable for every single currency, so just use an array in your struct, with an element type of `String: Double`

```swift
struct RatesResponse: Decodable, Hashable{
    let rates : [String: Double]
}
```

JSON key "rates" has a value of a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are doubles.

After decoding in your URLSession, you can do:

```swift
for rate in ratesResponse.rates {
    let currency = rate.key // AED, AFN, etc.
    let exchangeRate = rate.value // 3.671827, 80.098152, etc.
    // With these variables, you can append each of them to a new, separate array for use in your SwiftUI list.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining to me! After a few more revisions + what you suggested my code is working now and I understand it better!

Comment: I'm glad you understand. Don't hesitate to PM me if you have any more questions about parsing JSON data. It is definitely a confusing topic :)

Answer (score 1):

Your object model suggests that the value associated with `rates` key is another object with another `rates` key. But that doesn’t match the JSON you have provided. The value associated with top-level `rates` key is just a dictionary.

So you could do the following and be done with it:

```swift
struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
}
```

Or, if you want to capture everything in this JSON, you could add the additional properties:

```swift
struct Motd: Decodable {
    let msg: String
    let url: URL
}

struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let motd: Motd
    let success: Bool
    let base: String
    let date: Date
    let rates: [String: Double]
}
```

And then:

```swift
do {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    let responseObject = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    print(responseObject)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

FWIW, the `base`, `date`, and `rates` objects likely could/should be optionals, e.g.:

```swift
struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let motd: Motd
    let success: Bool
    let base: String?
    let date: Date?
    let rates: [String: Double]?
}
```

To confirm, we would need to see what a well-formed non-success response looks like. Glancing at the documentation it was not immediately obvious, but something like the above is likely what you want, where `JSONDecoder` would be able to successfully decode both success responses and failure responses.